# Swift CoreLocation

Tags: swift, location

For the following line of code:

```
let currentLocationCoordinates = locationManager.requestLocation()
```

I get this warning:

> Constant 'currentLocationCoordinates' inferred to have type 'Void',
>   which may be unexpected

In Info.plist I added this Keys:

- Privacy - Location Always and When In Use Usage Description
- Privacy - Location Always Usage Description
- Privacy - Location When In Use Usage Description

The ´locationManager´ is defined in class property:

```
let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
```

I have searched a lot and did not find any solution. Do you have any suggestions? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need

```
let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
locationManager.delegate = self
```

---

```
class MYVC:UIViewController,CLLocationManagerDelegate { --- }
```

---

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, 
       didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) { --- }
```

---

This `locationManager.requestLocation()` returns void not the current location , it starts the query for current location then call `didUpdateLocations` when gets it so you may `print(locations.last)` , also you may only need

> Privacy - Location Always and When In Use Usage Description

as it includes the 2 other permissions

Comment: Is there any opportunity to get only one time the current location coordinate to save in a constant?

Comment: declare a var and inside `didUpdateLocations` assign  `locations.last` to it  then do `locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()`